# While trying to pass touch coordinates to canvas in android studio receiving an error 'overrides nothing' on touch function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a circle drawn at the place user touches but I keep getting the ''setOnTouchEvent' overrides nothing' message. What could be the problem?

```
class TouchView(context : Context) : View(context) {


    var xTouch = 0f
    var yTouch = 0f
    val paint : Paint

    init {
        paint=Paint()
        paint.isFilterBitmap = true
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.color = Color.LTGRAY
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)

        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
        canvas.drawCircle(xTouch, yTouch, 50f, paint)

    }

    override fun setOnTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) : Boolean{
        xTouch = event.x
        yTouch= event.y

        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is as indicated by the error message. You're trying to override setOnTouchEvent but that doesn't exist in the base class (View).

Answer (score 0):

Use onTouchEvent there is no method named setOnTouchEvent as given [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))